# Sobolev space: Prove a function is in $W^{1,\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am reading the book: Fully nonlinear elliptic equations of Caffarelli and Cabre. In page 8 (Prop 1.2) they prove that if function $u$ in a convex domain locally has at least one paraboloid touching from above and one touching from below then $u$ is $C^{1,1}$.

The proof basically is by proving $u$ is differentiable, and then it has weak second derivative which is bounded (I can understand this part). Now, let assume that $u$ is differentiable and has weak second derivative which is bounded, the remaining part is the following:

Since $u_i:=\partial_i u \in W^{1,\infty}(B)$ and $B$ is convex, we have that $u_i$ is continuous and:

$$u_i(x)-u_i(y)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dt}u_i(tx+(1-t)y)\,dt=\sum\limits_{j}\int_{0}^{1} \partial_{ij}u(tx+(1-t)y)\,dt(x_j-y_j)$$

for any $x,y \in \bar{B}$.

Then using the boundedness of weak second derivative to have the Lipschitz continuity of first derivative.

My question is just they start from the assumption that  $u_i \in W^{1,\infty}(B)$ and I do not know why we have this? My problem is I do not know why $u_i \in L^{\infty}(B)$. Could anyone help me please. Thank you very much!

Comment: Because $D^2u\in L^\infty(B)$.

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't got it. Could you please explain for me why $D^2u \in L^{\infty}(B)$ then $u_i \in L^{\infty}(B)$?

Answer (score 0):

With no loss of generality, we may directly assume that $B_\varepsilon(x)\subset\Omega$ for any $x\in\bar B.$ Otherwise, we can choose an $\varepsilon'\in(0,\varepsilon)$ which is sufficient small, such that $B_{\varepsilon'}(x)\subset\Omega$ for any $x\in\bar B.$ So we have $\Theta(x,\varepsilon')\leq\Theta(x,\varepsilon)\leq K$ for any $x\in\bar B,$ and we replace $\varepsilon'$ by $\varepsilon.$

We note that $\Theta(x,\varepsilon)\leq K$ implies that there is a convex paraboloid $P$ with opening $K$ such that $P$ touches $u$ by above at $x\in\bar B$ in $B_\varepsilon(x)$, and also $\nabla P(x)=\nabla u(x)$. A straightforward calculation yields that $$P(y)=\frac{K}{2}\left|y-x+\frac{\nabla u(x)}{K}\right|^2+u(x)-\frac{|\nabla u(x)|^2}{2K},\ y\in B_\varepsilon(x).$$ By using that $u\leq P$ in $B_\varepsilon(x),$ we obtain that $$|\nabla u(x)|\leq\frac{C(K, |u|_{L^\infty}(\bar B),\mathrm{diam}(\bar B))}{\varepsilon}.$$ Thus $\nabla u\in L^\infty(\bar B).$